# Will I have problems re-entering England?

Tags: uk, schengen, international-travel, nigerian-citizens

I am from Nigeria and I was given a month visa to join my husband and children in the UK. I was given a resident permit that will expire in 2019. I want to travel to Portugal with my husband. Do I need a visa extension for my traveling and coming back to the UK?

Answer (score 6):

The 30-day visa is only relevant for your first entry, since your residence permit (BRP) can only be collected in the UK.

Now that you have a valid BRP, you only need that and a valid passport.

Should you lose your BRP sometime, you have to obtain a temporary visa to get back in.

Answer (score 2):

No.  With a valid residence permit, you do not need a visa.